# What are some nice places to visit and some exciting things to do in Cyprus?

Tags: recommendations, summer, cyprus

I am looking for a destination to go this summer in the net, and I have discovered a country called Cyprus, which looks very, very nice. Actually I am considering going with my friends there.

Do you know any good places for young people that we can explore, see things, and have fun?

Do you also have any suggestions?

Comment: nvest in a travel guide and/or read things like this: http://wikitravel.org/en/Cyprus . Limassol is a good place to pitch your tent. For the rest, it would be helpful if you were more precise about your interests. What are you young people interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to Cyprus in the summer, you'll need to gauge your activities to account for the arid, dry heat that overwhelms the island.  That means unless you are from some place like Nevada, it will take a while to acclimate.  Even the Med is hot during the summer months!

There's a degree of local night-life in the hotel districts, due to the way Cypriot visas work, you can expect to see older chaps dancing with women around 30+ years younger...

There's some Greek ruins that you'll need taxis or similar to reach.

For me, the most attractive feature of Cyprus is the cuisine.  The Cypriot specialty is 'kleftiko', and it's superb!

But if you're looking for the complete young crowds 'night-life-in-the-Med' experience, check out Ibiza.

Comment: Thanks a lot Garry. I also found Ayia Napa there in Cyprus, which seems also to have wonderful nightlife also. I do not think it is at the same level as Ibisa, but looks really amazing.